# transform an array of objects with map( )

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dictionary, object

I can't understand how the map () method works because all the examples are with numbers and to understand I need an example with something more specific.
so I made this
I have an array of objects:

```
 let people = [
   {
     id: 1,
     name: 'jhon',
     last_name: 'wilson'
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: 'maria',
     last_name: 'anyway'
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     name: 'lastOne',
     last_name: 'example'
   }
];
```

I want to understand how with `people.map();` i can change the idk, name?? of the 2nd element.
this is how i think `map()`  work:

```
people.map(() => {
     people[1].name = prompt()
// At this point i don't know how continue
})
```

I'm studying on my own, so I will be very grateful to you :)

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: [Array.prototype.map](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiV97_79dfyAhUIOisKHVDmAwYQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AOvVaw12XNJirv8-3J2POqmbqwb2) is what you want.

Comment: I know that the function returns a new array, I would like the same array of objects but that the 2nd element changes the name

Comment: @F.LucasPicco if you just want to change the second element's name (say to "Emily"), but in a separate array, then you can just do the following:

`const newArray = [...people]; // This copies the array using the spread operator`
`newArray[1].name = "Emily";`

Answer (score 2):

The `.map()` function will go through the entire array, and on each step of that process it will take the current item that we are looking at and will pass it as a parameter into the function. You can then do whatever you want to that item, and whatever you return from your function will replace what is in that position in the array.

Say for example, with the array you gave in your question, we wanted to remove the `name` and `last_name` properties, and combine them into a `full_name` property. We can do the following:

```js
 let people = [
   {
     id: 1,
     name: 'jhon',
     last_name: 'wilson'
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: 'maria',
     last_name: 'anyway'
   },
     id: 3,
     name: 'lastOne',
     last_name: 'example'
   }
];

people = people.map((person) => {
  return {
    id: person.id,
    full_name: `${person.name} ${person.last_name}`
  }
});
```

After this code runs, our `people` array would look like this:

```
[
   {
     id: 1,
     full_name: 'jhon wilson'
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     full_name: 'maria anyway'
   },
     id: 3,
     name: 'lastOne example'
   }
];
```

You can think of it as doing something very similar to this:

```js
function transformPerson(person) {
  return {
    id: person.id,
    full_name: `${person.name} ${person.last_name}`
  }
}

let newPeople = [];
for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  newPeople[i] = transformPerson(people[i])
}

people = newPeople;
```

Comment: thank you Ashley. this asnwer it was really helpingfull for me :)

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map()` takes in a function as a parameter, passes each item of the array into the function, and returns an array of the result.

For example, if I wanted to multiply each of the items in the array by 2:

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const y = x.map(v => v * 2) // result: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Note: `Array.map` does not affect the original array; it creates a new array of the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to

```js
let people = [{id:1,name:'john',last_name:'wilson'},{id:2,name:'maria',last_name:'anyway'},{id:3,name:'lastOne',last_name:'example'}];

people = people.map((p,i) =>({...p,name: i===1?prompt("New name"):p.name}))

console.log(people);
```

This will prompt the user only for a new name when `i===1`. The expression will create a new array that will be stored under the variable name `people` again. If you wanted `people` to remain unchanged you could assign the return value of the `people.map()`-call to a different variable (or constant).